# How to get an oriented contour from vtkMarchingSquares

Tags: computational-geometry, vtk, contour

I have a 2D array of double values, and I want to extract oriented contours at a particular threshold.  By "oriented" I mean that the values to the left of the direction of travel should be larger than the threshold, and the values to the right should be smaller.

I am trying to use `vtkMarchingSquares`, but it just gives me a bunch of tiny line segments across individual grid cells.  So I'm trying to stitch them together with `vtkStripper`.

But the contours come out fragmented, and not in a consistent orientation with respect to the underlying values.

I have also tried setting a `vtkMergePoints` locator in the `vtkMarchingSquares` object, but as far as I can tell, the locator's `SetTolerance` method has no effect on the output.

Comment: I think you're just going to walk through the edges and and re-orient them yourself.  I don't know if re-orienting will help vtkStripper connect lines.  If not, you'll probably have to connect them yourself too.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  Fairly disappointed with VTK's approach to this; if this is all `vtkMarchingSquares` does and there's no uniform way to fix it, I don't see how it's all that useful.  Anyway I found that `OpenCV` has contouring too, and it seems to be much easier to use and gives me what I want.

Comment: I have done it numerous times in 3D using the chain vtkMarchingCubes -> vtkPolyDataNormals -> vtkStripper. In 2D I have used vtkContourFilter -> vtkPolyDataNormals -> vtkStripper and they are perfectly oriented

Comment: Maybe apply vtkCleanPolyData to the line first?